# Rails 3 - how to set up the routes for example.com/whatever-i-need

Tags: url, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, url-routing

I have a little database with a movies that I saw. Now when I want to display a detail of a movie, so the profile of wanted movie is on the address `example.com/movies/21`.
But I would like to have a profile page of every movie on the nicer URL address, for example `example.com/lords-of-the-rings`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, store the url name into a new field, like `Movie.permalink`

In `config/routes.rb` :

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match "movies/:permalink" => "movies#show"
end
```

And in your controller :

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @movie = Movie.find_by_permalink( params[:permalink] )
  end
end
```

For more on routes in rails : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the slugged gem: https://github.com/Sutto/slugged

Many folks like this approach.
It's rails 3+

Answer (score -1):

Just to help guide the answers, would you allow something like:

```
http://example.com/movies/lord-of-the-rings
```

If so, grabbing the params[:id] from that URL is easy.

You can automate the generation of that last :id by changing to_param of the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param  # overridden
    name
  end
end
```

Then you could change the show method of the controller to reflect the new :id format.

```
user = User.find_by_name(params[:id])
```